# How to animate responsive div in Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, animation

I have following animation:

```
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [
        trigger('fade', [
          transition(':enter', [
              style({'width': '0' }),
              animate(300, style({'width': '?'})) // responsive width here what can I do?
          ]),
          transition(':leave', [
              animate(200, style({'width': '0px'}))
          ])
    
      ])
      ]
})
```

and the html code:

```
<div class="detail" *ngIf="hasPost" [@fade]>
    <app-post-detail></app-post-detail>
</div>
```

So, I generally wonder how to setup animations when the width is responsible or the height is just not known, because in the example above, the div with the class `detail` has different width-sizes:

```
.detail {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    width: 35%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: 20;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .detail{
        width: 50%;
    }
    
}
```

What would I do here? I tried to set the width to auto but the animation then looks awful. I have to pass the correct width for the animation to work but what if don't know the exact width or the height is just not known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of number for width give a * like below

```
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [
        trigger('fade', [
          transition(':enter', [
              style({'width': '*' }),
              animate(300, style({'width': '*'})) // responsive width here what can I do?
          ]),
          transition(':leave', [
              animate(200, style({'width': '*'}))
          ])
    
      ])
      ]
})
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! I will try it right now.

Comment: It does work, but I have a last question when using *ngIf. The content is seen before the div expands to its fullest height. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Yes, ask your question

Comment: I updated my comment from above. Do you have any idea how to solve this?